# "Invalid constant value" error for TabController

Tags: flutter, dart

I've worked with tabs before and this code bellow always worked. But I recently updated everything and as usual they broke something that was working perfectly and now I don't know how to make it work.

It's the exact same example as in [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html](https://It%27s%20the%20exact%20same%20example%20as%20in%20https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html)

Here's my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {  
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        bottom: const TabBar(
          controller: _tabController, //problem is here
          tabs: [...
```

When I assign "controller: _tabController" it throws "Invalid constant value".

I get it, TabBar.controller is expecting a constant. But how to work around this error?

Comment: Simply remove `const` before `TabBar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `const` keyword in front of `TabBar` widget

Answer (score 0):

add  ( with TickerProviderStateMixin )to your class like
class _Customer_BodyState extends State<Customer_Body>with TickerProviderStateMixin {}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).